# For each edge in a tree, counting paths passing through this edge

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, trees

I have a tree and for its each edge, I want to know the numbers paths passing through this edge.

For example: a tree with vertex-set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and edge-set = [(1,2), (2,3), (2,4), (4,5), (4,6)] Number of paths for each edge:

(1,2)-> 5

(2,3)-> 5

(2,4)-> 9

(4,5)-> 5

(4,6)-> 5

I am not able to think of any algorithm other than brute force (enumerating all paths of tree).

Please provide any linear/quadratic method.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 8 paths including $\{4,5\}$? Namely one for each combination of "vertex on one side of the chosen edge" (1,2,3, or 4) and "vertex on the other side of the chosen edge" (5 or 6).

Comment: @HenningMakholm you are correct, I updated the example. Actually 5 is not connected to 6, instead 4 is connected to 6.

Answer (score 3):

The answer mentioned above is $\mathcal{O}(N)$ for ONE edge but doing it for each one will make it $O(N^2)$.
Although we can compute the answer in O(N) total for all the edges.
I've added pseudocode for the algorithm at the end.
Steps: 
1) As we have a tree, we can root it at some node, say node 1.
2) Run a dfs and compute an array subtreeSize[], where subtreeSize[i] gives the size of the subtree rooted at node i,(Subtree of a node x contains node x as well as all those nodes which passes through x to reach the root in shortest path).
[I've added the pseudocode for computing subtreeSize array at the end]
3) Now that we have this array computed, for each edge {u,v} we know for sure either of these is a parent and other is the child. Lets say u is parent and v is its child. Now let A = subtreeSize[v], then answer for this edge will be (N - A) * (A).
Why? Because we have these two sets of nodes, lets say we remove the {u,v} edge then the we'll get 2 trees, say all nodes in u side are in set X and all nodes in v side are in set Y. Then we can see that for each node in set X we can make a path to each node in set Y that crosses the {u,v} edge. So total number of paths will be = |X| * |Y|, (|setS| = size of setS). You can achieve this whole step in the same dfs if you notice closely whie computing subtreeSize

**pseudocode for the complete O(N) algorithm:**

**dfs(node, parent):**

```
subtreeSize[node] = 1
for each child c of node do:
    dfs(c, node)
    subtreeSize[node] = subtreeSize[node] + subtreeSize[c]
 answerForEdge[node and parent] = (N - subtreeSize[node])*(subtreeSize[node]) // N is the total number of nodes
 return
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange community! The quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most benefit from your time here. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations.

Answer (score 1):

If the edge is, say, {u,v}, it seems to me that you should be able to do a BFS from u (not including v) and a BFS from v (not including u).

From the BFS from u (omitting v), count the number of vertices you visit and add one to it (for u). This should be the number of paths leading to the u end of the edge (including the trivial path of just starting at u). Call this n(u).

Do the same thing from v (omitting u): count the number of vertices you visit and add one to it (for v). This will be the number of paths leading to the v end of the edge (including the trivial path of starting at v). Call this n(v).

Then you can simply multiply these together to get all the paths passing through edge {u,v}: the product is basically picking a path to u (of which there are n(u) such paths) and then picking a path to v (of which there are n(v) such paths).

BFS, on a tree, runs in O(V), where V is the number of nodes in the tree, so two BFS algorithms also run in time O(V) as well: thus, the algorithm is linear in the number of vertices. Indeed, since the double BFS visits every vertex exactly once, it can be done in V steps precisely.

You'll note that this works with your example: for instance, if we take {2,4}, starting a BFS at 2 gives us 2 vertices, namely 1 and 3, so:

n(2) = 2 + 1 = 3.

(Remember we add 1 for vertex 2 itself.)

Then, starting a BFS at 4 also gives us 2 vertices, namely 5 and 6, so:

n(4) = 2 + 1 = 3

(Remember that we add 1 for vertex 4 itself.)

Thus, the total number of paths through edge {2,4} is:

n(2) * n(4) = 3 * 3 = 9.

Comment: vorpal the solution mentioned by you will be O(n^2) not O(n) as you have to do it for each edge.

Comment: @manofp It will be a linear time. Think.
Hint: use post order traversal

Comment: A tree over n vertices has exactly n-1 edges, so it's not O(n^2) but O(n).
For generic graphs, it is O(V + E), where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges. In this case, E = V-1, so O(V + (V-1)) = O(V) as desired.